# Can't edit files in Vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've just started using Vscode and have a created a WebAPI project. On trying to open any of the default code files (Startup.cs and Program.cs) whatever I type starts to appear in the blue bar as shown below instead of where I have placed the cursor. I have no idea what's going on or what that blue bar is.

I am able to add my own code files and edit these as I would expect.

I'm running Vscode 1.29.1 on Win 10 on a Dell Latitude 12 7275. The vscode extension

[image: screenshot]

Enabled extensions :

[image: Enabled extensions]

Answer (score 62, accepted):

That's caused by Vim extension. Uninstall or disable it, otherwise use insert key on your keyboard to put it in insert mode.

Comment: I just discovered that my keyboard doesn't have an `INS` key.  But the `I` key works.  Realizing that it was Vim was the most helpful thing there.  I had installed the extension because I thought it would add the Vim program to the integrated terminal, because my computer also doesn't have Vim...

Comment: Very weird, I have never installed the VIM extension, but it was installed and removing it resolved my issue...

Comment: it works when i uninstall the vim extension.

Comment: How awesome! Now I can use vim commands in Code

Answer (score 3):

I'l leave this here for future readers

Basically, if I split files in tabs in VS Code, I could work with the files on the left hand side but could "read-only" all the files on the right hand side.

When I went to the extensions tabs I noticed that whatever I typed was being typed in the field in the extensions search bar. After deleting that, and clicking back on the "Files" tab, it went back to normal and can basically edit files on the both sides of my split screen.

1. If cannot type
2. Check where whatever you type is going (e.g. Extensions > Search bar)
3. Delete wherever it's being typed, and click back on the "Files tab"
4. Check if it works

Comment: Good deduction! But it still keeps happening. Did you find out how to fix it?

Comment: `ctrl+shift+x` is the shortcut for find in extensions, maybe theres the connection.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling VIM  worked for me; the number one problem for most of the day

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the parent folders permission...

Try changing the entire folder to:

```
Read & Write: Allows a user to open the item and change it.
```

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-permissions-for-files-folders-or-disks-mchlp1203/mac

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me. I had a Vim extension enabled in vscode. Disable it if you have one installed. You can go to your extensions and type vim. You should be able to see the one you installed and disable it.

Comment: It's the same as the answer from 2019: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58208081/2745495